# Cannot modify header information facebook sharing error in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am receiving "Cannot modify header information-headers already sent by(output started at /home/content/31/90..../html/.../system/core/Exceptions.php:185)" message for facebook sharing in iOS 8

My Code is :

```
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:url_to_link];
params.name = @"App Name";
params.caption = @"";
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:icon_url];
params.description = @"";
```

Comment: If the answer is working then Please accept and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution for this error is passing string value to params.description.